# What does "TEOP BE Branch" mean?

Tags: financial-statements, belgium

My financial statements contain a transaction to "TEOP BE Branch". The transaction has no other metadata. What does this transaction mean? Searching for this string doesn't turn up anything.

I'm in Belgium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's shorthand for "Takeaway Europe Operations Belgium Branch". This was a transaction in the Takeaway food delivery app.